# Getting internal server error when setting up .htaccess file to web.config file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, iis, web-config

I am trying to upload codeigniter project on windows server. when i uploades project on windows server my index page running perfectly but wheb i enter username and password to login page an error come with message.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070003
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
Config File    \\?\D:\Inetpub\vhosts\sp-tapi.in\clean-note.rudra-infotech.com\test\web.config
Requested URL      http://clean-note.rudra-infotech.com:80/test
Physical Path      D:\Inetpub\vhosts\sp-tapi.in\clean-note.rudra-infotech.com\test
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

I have converted my .htaccess file to web.config file for IIS server (using IIS 8.5)
my web.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="rule 1S" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/somedir/oops404.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had identical issue, please check with this modifications, it worked for me.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>

    <system.webServer>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I modify web.config file according to your answer but , its not working.

Comment: I solve the issue browser was automatically include space before call controller.  Like it. https://abc-rudra-infotech.com/%20test

Comment: Thank you. It did help me to find my problem as well.